# How to get values Shader in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have material with Shader in unity.
How to get a value in code?
For example, i need change value EdgeWidth in code, how can i do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.html), you need to find your material or your shader, in your script, and you have a lot of functions to change the value of a material, like [`.SetFloat()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetFloat.html).

```
Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
rend.material.SetFloat("EdgeWidth", -1.18f);
```